# How to resolve "module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'"

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, import

I am trying to build a deep learning model but I am getting an error using tensorflow and I am failing to fix this issue. The error is:

> module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'

Code:

```
import csv
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import numpy as ndarray
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from numpy import zeros, newaxis
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder 
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras import layers
from keras.layers import Input, Add, Dense, Activation, ZeroPadding1D, BatchNormalization, Flatten, Conv1D, AveragePooling1D, MaxPooling1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D
from keras.models import Model, load_model
from keras.initializers import glorot_uniform
from tensorflow.keras import backend
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
import tensorflow.keras


def IntelNet(input_shape = (22,1), classes = 2):
    # Define the input as a tensor with shape input_shape

    X_input = Input(input_shape)


    # Zero-Padding
    #X = ZeroPadding1D(padding=1)(X_input)


     # Stage 1
    X = Conv1D(128, 4, strides = 1, name = 'conv1',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', padding = 'SAME')(X_input)
    X = BatchNormalization(name = 'bn_conv1')(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)
    #X = MaxPooling1D((3), strides=(2),padding = 'SAME')(X)


 # output layer
    X = Flatten()(X)
    X = Dense(classes, activation='softmax')(X)


    # Create model
    model = Model(inputs = X_input, outputs = X, name='ResNet50')

    return model




model = IntelNet(input_shape = (22,1), classes = 2)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-132-27edc41dcb88> in <module>
----> 1 model = IntelNet(input_shape = (22,1), classes = 2)

<ipython-input-130-31ea437308f9> in IntelNet(input_shape, classes)
      2     # Define the input as a tensor with shape input_shape
      3 
----> 4     X_input = Input(input_shape)
      5 
      6 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_layer.py in Input(shape, batch_shape, name, dtype, sparse, tensor)
    176                              name=name, dtype=dtype,
    177                              sparse=sparse,
--> 178                              input_tensor=tensor)
    179     # Return tensor including _keras_shape and _keras_history.
    180     # Note that in this case train_output and test_output are the same pointer.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_layer.py in __init__(self, input_shape, batch_size, batch_input_shape, dtype, input_tensor, sparse, name)
     37         if not name:
     38             prefix = 'input'
---> 39             name = prefix + '_' + str(K.get_uid(prefix))
     40         super(InputLayer, self).__init__(dtype=dtype, name=name)
     41 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in get_uid(prefix)
     72     """
     73     global _GRAPH_UID_DICTS
---> 74     graph = tf.get_default_graph()
     75     if graph not in _GRAPH_UID_DICTS:
     76         _GRAPH_UID_DICTS[graph] = defaultdict(int)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'
```

How can I solve this problem? I am using Anaconda with Python 3.

Comment: which versions of keras and tensorflow are you using? they are probably not compatible

Comment: You are mixing ```keras``` and ```tensorflow.keras``` packages in your imports.

Comment: Only TensorFlow 1.x versions have `tf.reset_default_graph()`. You probably have TF 2.x installed and trying to run a TF 1.x compatible code.

Comment: @kapil kap's, Can you please confirm if the error is resolved with the comment mentioned above?